# In Einstein's "relativity of simultaneity" thought experiment, would not the passenger on the train see a dimmer signal?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, time-dilation, relative-motion, thought-experiment

This is the updated, more precise question--is this a paradox?:

> Suppose a rocket traveling close to the velocity of light which emits
>   a single photon from its midpoint at point A, illustrated below.  The rocket is equipped with a single detector drawn in green at the front of the rocket.  The velocity of light is independent of the velocity of the source, and thus an earthbound observer will note the photon's spherically-symmetric probabilistic wavefront expanding in the form of of the larger red circle C.  An observer on the rocket will note the photon's spherically-symmetric probabilistic wavefront expanding in the form of of the smaller black circle D.
>
> Let us run this single-photon experiment numerous times.  Because the
>   detector illustrated in green occupies a larger portion of the smaller
>   Circle D, the observer on the spaceship will see the photon detected
>   more often by the detector than will the earthbound observer.  Because
>   the detector illustrated in green occupies a smaller portion of circle
>   C, the earthbound observer will see the photon detected less often at
>   the detector than the rocket's observer.
>
> [image]
>
> One could imagine surrounding both Circle C and Circle D with similar
>   detectors along the entire circumference.  One could perform the
>   single-photon experiment numerous times on numerous trips, using only the detectors on
>   Circle C or only the detectors on Circle D.
>
> On average, the earthbound observer will see the photon hit the illustrated green detector less
>   often than will the observer on the rocket.
>
> Can both the observer on earth and the rocket be right?  IS not there
>   a paradox here?

Suppose two flashes of light of equal intensity.  If one measures one further away from the other, it will appear dimmer.  And so it is that the passenger on Einstein's train will see the lightning flash behind them to be dimmer than the one in front of him.

In Einstein's book on relativity, he writes,

> We suppose a very long train travelling along the rails with the
>   constant velocity v and in the direction indicated in Fig 1.
>
> [image: Einstein Figure 1]
>
> People
>   travelling in this train will with a vantage view the train as a rigid
>   reference-body (co-ordinate system); they regard all events in
>   reference to the train. Then every event which takes place along the
>   line also takes place at a particular point of the train. Also the
>   definition of simultaneity can be given relative to the train in
>   exactly the same way as with respect to the embankment. As a natural
>   consequence, however, the following question arises :
>
> Are two events (e.g. the two strokes of lightning A and B) which are
>   simultaneous with reference to the railway embankment also
>   simultaneous relatively to the train? We shall show directly that the
>   answer must be in the negative.
>
> When we say that the lightning strokes A and B are simultaneous with
>   respect to be embankment, we mean: the rays of light emitted at the
>   places A and B, where the lightning occurs, meet each other at the
>   mid-point M of the length A arrow B of the embankment. But the events
>   A and B also correspond to positions A and B on the train. Let M1 be
>   the mid-point of the distance A arrow B on the travelling train. Just
>   when the flashes (as judged from the embankment) of lightning occur,
>   this point M1 naturally coincides with the point M but it moves
>   towards the right in the diagram with the velocity v of the train. If
>   an observer sitting in the position M1 in the train did not possess
>   this velocity, then he would remain permanently at M, and the light
>   rays emitted by the flashes of lightning A and B would reach him
>   simultaneously, i.e. they would meet just where he is situated. Now in
>   reality (considered with reference to the railway embankment) he is
>   hastening towards the beam of light coming from B, whilst he is riding
>   on ahead of the beam of light coming from A. Hence the observer will
>   see the beam of light emitted from B earlier than he will see that
>   emitted from A. Observers who take the railway train as their
>   reference-body must therefore come to the conclusion that the
>   lightning flash B took place earlier than the lightning flash A. We
>   thus arrive at the important result:
>
> Events which are simultaneous with reference to the embankment are not
>   simultaneous with respect to the train, and vice versa (relativity of
>   simultaneity). Every reference-body (co-ordinate system) has its own
>   particular time ; unless we are told the reference-body to which the
>   statement of time refers, there is no meaning in a statement of the
>   time of an event.

And so it is that the passenger on Einstein's train will see the lightning flash behind them to be dimmer than the one in front of him.  Is this not true?

Indeed if the passenger is traveling very close to c, the flash from behind them will appear to be very, very dim, as the intensity of light falls of as $r^2$.  Is this not true?

Let us replace the two lightning strikes with light bulbs which the stationary observer standing at M observes to flash at the exact same time, just like the lightning strikes did. Will not the observer on the train conclude that the lightbulb behind them is dimmer than the one in front of them?

(@knzhou answers "Yes" below in the comments.)

Suppose then we consider a traveler on a spaceship with two light bulbs at either end, replacing the lightning strikes.

[image]

The space ship is traveling at .9 c relative to the earth.  Will the traveler not see the flash from the light bulb behind him to be dimmer?

Comment: Yes, redshift occurs? What is the question?

Comment: @knzhou also, light intensity falls of as r^2.  do you admit that light intensity falls off as r^2?  do you admit this is different from your redshift?  Will not the passenger thus see a dimmer signal due to the fact they are further away and light intensity falls off as r^2?  That is my question, as stated above.

Comment: This depends on the kind of light. For example, if we model the lightning strike as a cylindrical source, it's actually a $1/r$ falloff. But generally, yes.

Comment: Yes @knzhou, but the intensity still falls off.

Comment: Yes. $\hspace{0mm}$

Comment: @knzhou let us replace the two lightning strikes with light bulbs which the stationary observer standing at M observes to go flash at the exact same time, just like the lightning strikes did.  will not the observer on the train conclude that the lightbulb behind them is dimmer than the one in front of them?

Comment: Yes. $\hspace{0mm}$

Comment: How the intensity falls off (that's a quantity that depends on dimensionality, not Lorentz symmetry) is completely irrelevant, though, so what's the question?

Comment: @CuriousOne stop harassing me with nonsense like you have done repeatedly.  I will report you to the mods.

Comment: Dear @knzhou , I just updated the original question with a new figure--please see it above.  "Suppose then we consider a traveler on a spaceship with two light bulbs at either end, replacing the lightning strikes.
The space ship is traveling at .9 c relative to the earth. Will the traveler not see the flash from the light bulb behind him to be dimmer?"

Comment: Ah, as I suspected, this whole thing was an attempt to detect absolute motion. No, the back light in the spaceship is not dimmer, because these lights are traveling with the observer!

Comment: @knzhou suppose that we replace the lightbulbs with lighting strikes.  would the flash from the lightning strike in the rear appear dimmer?

Comment: See, here's the issue. How are the lightning strikes made? They're made from vibrating electrons in the air, and the air is moving with the ship. So this case is _exactly_ the same as the case with light bulbs, and the rear lightning strike does not appear dimmer in the spaceship case.

Comment: Whether or not a lightning strike appears dimmer depends on your relative velocity to the _air_. Not on 'absolute' velocity, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @knzhou suppose we replace the lightning strikes with strikes from laser beams of equal energy.  will the signal from the rear appear to be dimmer when the observer on the spaceship detects it?

Comment: This depends on the relative velocity between the observer and the laser apparatus. If they're all sitting inside the spaceship, the rear laser is not dimmer.

Comment: This whole scenario is a nice puzzle to think about, though. Tough cases like these are how one really learns relativity!

Comment: Yes @knzhou it is quite fun!  Thanks for your insights!   I have updated the question above with a related, more precise thought experiment.  Would love to hear your thoughts!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick reprise of the situation:

[image: Train]

This is the view in the embankment rest frame at $t=0$. We'll take the train to have a length $2d$ and we'll choose the origins so the middle of the train is at the origin in both frames. To find out where the flashes occur in the train frame we use the Lorentz transformations and the results are:

$$ F^\prime_{\,1}(t,x) = \left(\gamma\frac{vd}{c^2}, -\gamma d\right) $$

$$ F^\prime_{\,2}(t,x) = \left(-\gamma\frac{vd}{c^2}, \gamma d\right) $$

So according to the passenger on the train the distance to both flashes is the same, but flash $2$ happens before flash $1$ so the passenger sees the light from $F_2$ before he sees the light from $F_1$.

The thought experiment is really intended to show breakdown of simultaneity i.e. that in the embankment frame the flashes are simutaneous while in the train frame they are not. However we can extend the experiment to consider intensity as well.

In the train frame the flashes occur at an equal distance, so the light from them travels an equal distance and therefore the $1/r^2$ factor is the same for both.

In the embankment frame the light travels different distances because the light from $F_1$ travels a longer distance to reach the passenger than the light from $F_2$ does, so the $1/r^2$ factor is different for the two flashes. How do we explain the difference?

The solution is simply that for the passenger on the train the light is Doppler shifted because the flashes are moving relative to him. Remember that Doppler shift changes intensity as well as frequency. Although the passenger sees the light from both flashes travelling the same distance, he sees $F_1$ to be red shifted and less intense while $F_2$ is blue shifted and more intense.

Now we consider the situation where the you replace the lightning flashes with light bulbs that are stationary with respect to the train. Now the passenger sees both flashes as equal brightness. How do we explain what the embankment observer sees?

And again the solution is just the Doppler shift. Now the embankment observer sees $F_1$ to be blue shifted and $F_2$ to be read shifted i.e. $F_1$ is brighter than $F_2$. So even though the light from $F_1$ has to travel farther, it's brighter to start with.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation @JohnRennie !  I have updated the question above with a related, more precise thought experiment.  Would love to hear your thoughts!